# Proper way to import and use node modules with Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm just starting to use Laravel (v 8.x) Mix in a project, and am finding it frustrating to implement Javascript from node modules.

To begin, I have this in my `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.js('node_modules/mxgraph/javascript/mxClient.min.js', 'public/js');
mix.js('resources/js/*.js', 'public/js').postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
]).version();
```

Next, my `app.js` contains the following:

```
import Canvas from './canvas';

require('mxgraph');

const canvas = new Canvas();
```

...which imports `canvas.js`:

```
export default class Canvas {
    constructor() {
        this.container = document.getElementById('graphContainer');
        if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported())
        {
            // Displays an error message if the browser is not supported.
            alert('Browser is not supported!');
        }
.
.
.
    }
}
```

...and in the Scripts section of my Blade layout:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/mxClient.min.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

When I load the page, I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mxClient is not defined
    at new Canvas (app.js:3866)
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:3813)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:114081)
    at app.js:114143
    at app.js:114149
```

`var mxClient` is definitely present in `mxClient.min.js`, and the reference to it in `Canvas` occurs after it's loaded.

I've tried a bunch of variations, and nothing seems to work. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this. Is the canvas [CanvasJs](https://canvasjs.com/)? And mxclient - is that coming from mxGraph or a separate file?

Comment: Thanks! The canvas will be created in a Blade file that’s included in the layout.  It has a div with the id of `graphContainer`.  Mix pulls in `build.js` from `node_modules/mxgraph` and uses this to import `mxClient` and a bunch of other files.

Comment: Ok, but I need to know the js libraries. Is that the CnvasJs lib - https://canvasjs.com/?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  It’s here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mxgraph   (`npm install mxgraph`)

Comment: Ok, and why do you import `mxClient` separately in your `webpach.mix.js` and additionally `mxgraph` in your `app.js`?

Comment: Ok, got it. I'll check

Comment: Still, what is unclear, what your `canvas.js` is. Is it a custom thing you wrote, an npm package - if yes, which one?

Comment: Yes, `canvas.js` is my custom implementation.  It’s based on stuff that my coworker wrote in my last job. It gets compiled into `app.js`, along with a bunch of other custom code that I’m not showing, but which works just fine

Comment: As for why I import `mxClient` separately: lack of knowledge, and a bit of flailing around trying to get something to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227790/discussion-between-mpemburn-and-codedge).

Answer (score 1):

So, after playing around I found what you can do.

**Assemble one file**

Put `mxClient.min.js` and `app.js` into one file by doing

```js
mix.js(
    [
        "resources/js/app.js",
        "node_modules/mxgraph/javascript/mxClient.min.js",
    ],
    "public/js"
).postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
]).version();
```

**Import `mxGraph` and Canvas**

In your `app.js` you can put that

```js
import "./canvas";

require("mxgraph");

const canvas = new Canvas();
```

and `npm run dev` runs without issues.

### Update

I found a (maybe easier) option. Don't include `mxClient` in your `webpack.mix.js`, only your `app.js` is needed.

```js
// app.js

window.mxClient = new require("mxgraph")().mxClient;

let isBrowserSupported = mxClient.isBrowserSupported();

console.log(isBrowserSupported);
```

Comment: That does get `npm run dev` to run, but it still isn't seeing `mxClient` when I load the Blade file with `canvas.js` in the browser.  Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: I updated my answer. You only need to `require` the `mxGraph` lib in your `app.js`.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot more poking and searching around, I found a method that works.  It was based on what I found here:

https://www.programmersought.com/article/85491421858/

My implementation seems a bit clunky, but it does work, and I can now continue the project I'm trying to develop with mxGraph.

Thus, I no longer pull in `mxgraph` explicitly in `webpack.mix.js`, so it now reverts to the Laravel default:

```
mix.js('resources/js/*.js', 'public/js').postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
]).version();
```

I've also removed `require('mxgraph');` from `app.js`, so it just looks like this:

```
import Canvas from './canvas';

const canvas = new Canvas();
```

My `canvas.js` now looks like this:

```
import mx from 'mxgraph';

const mxgraph = mx({
    mxImageBasePath: './src/images',
    mxBasePath: './src'
});

window.mxGraph = mxgraph.mxGraph;
window.mxGraphModel = mxgraph.mxGraphModel;
window.mxEvent = mxgraph.mxEvent;
window.mxEditor = mxgraph.mxEditor;
window.mxGeometry = mxgraph.mxGeometry;
window.mxRubberband = mxgraph.mxRubberband;
window.mxDefaultKeyHandler = mxgraph.mxDefaultKeyHandler;
window.mxDefaultPopupMenu = mxgraph.mxDefaultPopupMenu;
window.mxStylesheet = mxgraph.mxStylesheet;
window.mxDefaultToolbar = mxgraph.mxDefaultToolbar;

const {mxGraph, mxClient, mxEvent, mxCodec, mxUtils, mxConstants, mxPerimeter, mxRubberband} = mxgraph;

export default class Canvas {
    constructor() {
        let container = document.getElementById('graphContainer');
        if (typeof(mxClient) !== 'undefined') {
            this.draw(container);
        }
    }

    draw (container) {
        if (! mxClient.isBrowserSupported())
        {
            // Displays an error message if the browser is not supported.
            mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
        }
        else
        {
            // Disables the built-in context menu
            mxEvent.disableContextMenu(container);

            // Creates the graph inside the given container
            var graph = new mxGraph(container);

            // Enables rubberband selection
            new mxRubberband(graph);

            // Gets the default parent for inserting new cells. This
            // is normally the first child of the root (ie. layer 0).
            var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

            // Adds cells to the model in a single step
            graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
            try
            {
                var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Hello,', 20, 20, 80, 30);
                var v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'World!', 200, 150, 80, 30);
                var e1 = graph.insertEdge(parent, null, '', v1, v2);
              
            }
            finally
            {
                // Updates the display
                graph.getModel().endUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the code in the `draw()` method is taken from an mxGraph "Hello World" demo (https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/manual.html).

Many thanks to @codedge for the time you spent helping me!

Comment: That also looks like a good way. The hazzle is mostly because the of the old code base of mxGraph (I guess). Anyway, good that you found something that works for you.